# How can multiple method calls be chained on slim's response object?

Tags: php, api, slim

I want to chain multiple method calls on slims's $response object, but if i do i get an error ( status 500) and nothing happens.
This might aswell be a lack of basic PHP knowledge, i am not very experienced in PHP and it is my first time working with slim, or any serverside / API framework for that matter.

I have tried flipping arround the order of the calls, and doing them in different lines but to no awail. The long term goel of this, to build an API for an update application. So i will have to handle get requests with multiple parameters, evaluate them and depending on the results, do and return deffirent responses.

```php
// this one fails, i set the status to 900 on purpose just to see what happens
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Slim main page")->withStatus(900);
    return $response;
});
```

The first example does give me an 500 error on the network tab. This would suggest some type of syntax error i guess? If i alter this route a little bit to look like this :

```php
# this one works fine, except the status code setting gets ignored, but why?
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $response->write("Slim main page")->withStatus(900);
    return $response;
});
```

things alsmost work out, but the status code is not set for some reason.

I would expect the first one, to return the string "slim main page" with the status code 900. Even if i use a non made up status code, this setting gets ignored.

The second code block ist just an alteration for testing purposes.

I am pretty sure this a newby thing but i am really lost here, so any advice, or some fool proof articles / docs besides the slim docs are appreciated.

Comment: As far as i know, i am not using any middlerwares, i have a minimal php server and basicly just the php file containig the shown code, and some other experimental functions. 

But i turned on error logging and got this :
Message: Call to a member function withStatus() on integer

Comment: Now I see what's wrong. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write` method returns the number of bytes written to the stream (and not the new response object). Try this:

```php
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args = []) {
    $response->getBody()->write('Slim main page');
    $response = $response->withStatus(200);

    return $response;
});
```

Notice 1: Enable the error details on dev: `'displayErrorDetails' => true`

Notice 2: The HTTP code 900 is an invalid status code for Slim and will throw the following execption.

```
Type: InvalidArgumentException
Message: Invalid HTTP status code
File: vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/Response.php
Line: 228
```

Comment: If i change the code accordingly, i get an error, explaining me that my status code is invalid. I changed the statuscode to 400, application works, but the status code shown in the browser is still 200

Comment: i Think i figured it out, the $response object is imutable, so if want to change something, say the status code, i need to create a new intance of the object 

```php
$response->getBody()->write("Slim main page");
$test = $response->withStatus(401);
$response->write($response);
return $test;
```

Now the site displays, the old 200 code from $response, but the browser itself says it is a 401
Still marking you answer as accepted since you got me on the right tracks